# How to make Product List in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to display Product list in ASP.net C#? i'm creating e-commerce website for my thesis i need to display it in a grid form like this >> [sample product list](http://pcx.com.ph/components/processors.html?p=2) with limitation per page example 10 products per page please i need your help

[image: My Product Database]

Comment: One method can be using `GridView` with `TemplateFields`

Comment: Start From Here, [Shopping Cart](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/aspnet-creating-shopping-cart-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `DataList` control. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498210.aspx#aspnett29basicdatalistcs_topic3) you can find a good tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do that. There's no one right or correct solution. It all depends where you're comfortable workin' with.

Can you please show us what you've already done?

Now with regards to the filtering, you may use a combination of GridView + DropDownList (where DDL will be used to filter the result). You can look for some great tutorials online.

I hope it helps you.